# io:netty.ConnecTimedOutException: Connection timed out

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I clicked Multiplayer, click join server(Hypiexl Network, us.hypiexl.net). Minecraft will show me 'Connecting to the server...', then it will show:

io:netty.ConnecTimedOutException: Connection timed out

I use Minecraft Java Edition 1.14.4 on a Mac. My Java is the lasted version JRE 8. My firewall is off. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hello! Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very 'gaming' related question, but that error is caused by the network you're connected to (your Wi-Fi). A time out is caused after it has tried and failed to connect over and over.

Try to restart your router or call your ISP if the problem persists.

Comment: I changed my router for two times(Because of Moving Home), but it's still not working!